# How to use Windows credentials to bind to Active Directory?

Tags: java, spring, active-directory, ldap, spring-ldap

I try to lookup some information from Active Directory using Spring LDAP. I get the following error:

```
Uncategorized exception occured during LDAP processing; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C0906E8, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v1db1]; remaining name '/'
```

As far as I know, I get this error because I did not perform a bind using a technical account. This is because I have none.

Is it possible to configure Spring LDAP to use the credentials of the currently logged in user (e.g. my credentials)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I am not sure about using getting permissions for your Spring app using your already logged in windows session. But I do think you could just use **ldp.exe** from Microsoft to solve your problem.  With ldp you can bind using `DOMAIN\samaccountname` and password.  You could bind as yourself and then look up your DN.  Then you can use your DN and password to bind in the Spring app.

Or you could just wander down to the AD admins and ask them what your DN is.

Comment: I have got a technical account now and use it for binding to AD. This is probably a approach then using my windows session.